# Слитное или раздельное написание слов

Tags: морфология

Подскажите, как правильно написать: пофиг или по фиг?

Comment: Если хотите грязно выругаться с насильственно-сексуальным подтекстом - то раздельно, по+предмет. А если хотите завернуть что-то многозначительное и глубокомысленное - то слитно, конечно, так как наречие, весьма образное и литературно-философское. Ну и само-собой лучше не ругаться, подкрепляя комплексы, а смотреть на жизнь шире.

Comment: Да, и если выберете первый вариант, то ударение-таки лучше ставить на существительное, а не на предлог, чтобы не было сомнений, по что или куда нужно идти.

Comment: Есть интересный анекдот на эту тему pikabu.ru/story/rozental_lakonichno_640684 Там Розенталь как бы отвечает на "похожий" вопрос. И вот у него для двух вариантов  учитывается ударение, а также четко определена разница в семантике  :)

Comment: И еще (это уже по комментариям):  Жаль, что не стали отвечать на вопрос про "таки". Как правильно записать:  ударение-таки или ударение таки? Есть, конечно, определенная рекомендация в правиле, но уж очень формально это правило звучит.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, уважаемый Буратино, за обстоятельный ответ и за разъяснение. Мне это очень помогло. С уважением,

Comment: @Sharon забавно, что я попал, да в целом согласен с Розенталем, хотя в Иордане даже не нырял. Про таки тоже не знаю, а генетической памяти не имею по этому вопросу, мне просто иногда нравится стилистически подражать.) И забавно, что на грамоте_ру пишут только про первый вариант, неужели филологам так нравится браниться нецензурными словами, зачем они этому учат, а не философии языка? Даже на педивикии два варианта) хотя там оба обсценные, но это другое, им можно и так...

Comment: Кстати, еще такой момент, если писать, то нужно ставить запятую: а мне, пофиг; иди ты, нафиг. По аналогии к "иди ты, к чёрту." Эти слова, это не брань, а остановка брани, мог бы дальше начать ругаться, но остановился на этом слове. В то время как в том же английском брань действительно брань и даже больше - проклятье: go to hell  - иди в ад, ну а про мазафака я молчу). В русской классике в большинстве случаев ставили запятую, когда писали "к чёрту", потому что пожелание зла другому само собой уже грех, хотя тоже не все.

Comment: Но ставили не все, что тоже показательно. То есть с запятой смысл: "иди ты(хочет проклясть или выругаться, но потом), к чёрту(оставляет проклятие чёрту, а не человеку)".
Русский мат - не брань, хотя его можно использовать для ругани и еще его очень хотят сделать именно бранью. В русском нет плохих или хороших слов, есть плохие или хорошие пожелания.

Comment: @Буратино
 Не скажу за всех филологов, но в некоторых издательствах мат используют часто, в том числе женщины. Видно, работа сейчас очень нервная, доходчивее не скажешь. Варианты, по-моему, такие: мне всё пофиг, пошел на фиг. А вот по поводу запятой перед  "к черту" сомневаюсь, это же тоже посыл куда-нибудь подальше (тесное прилегание обстоятельства к глаголу).

Comment: @Sharon да, выдаю наверное желаемое за действительное, хотя Гоголь и ряд классиков очень аккуратно оформляли чертыхания, отдельным восклицанием. А вот начиная где-то с Булгакова начинается и к чёрту и к чёртовой матери). В том числе когда пишут дурак или идиот о себе, тогда обособляют часто. Вот из позднего :"Он, дурак, даже не знал..." - Ф. Искандер, хотя :"В таких случаях дурак бежит впереди всех." Или ближе к 90-м Гревкова "А он, дурак, не понимал," но она же: "Нацарапал гвоздем на стене: " Бурнаков дурак ". Мне кажется, интонационная запятая в ругательствах - очень интересная тема)

Comment: Да, дурак –  это оценка других или самого себя в роли обособленного приложения, отнесенного к местоимению. Обособление в этом случае не зависит от позиции приложения. Вот так это  правило звучит, по науке как бы:)